# Does the level 4 Serpentis power include the level 2 and 3 powers?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages, vampire-20th-anniversary, vampire-the-dark-ages-20a

In the context of Vampire: The Dark Ages 20th Anniversary edition.

The level 4 Serpentis power allows the vampire to transform into a hideous snake-creature. Does this also include the Typhonic Maw and Serpent's Flesh powers? I.e., when the level 4 power is invoked, does the vampire also gain the benefits of the other two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, those are separate powers that each require their own blood cost, as per page 252. However, once you activate them, you can use them together.